# AWS: Update instance type to a non-supported instance type by the AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using "[MariaDB 10.0.10 on Ubuntu 14.04](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp?sku=azr9of26aa7qfvrakvuen8gnr)" on an m1.large instance. I am unable to update to m3.large due to the fact that it is unsupported by the AMI. How can I bypass this?

I have tried making an image directly from the instance. I tried making a snapshot from the volume then making an AMI from it. Both did not work.

Comment: You are not able to change the instance type? Not option is shown or greyed out?

Comment: On the linked marketplace page there are several instance types listed and not the m3.large.  For some reason the people bundling the software didn't allow m3.large.  I note that MariaDB is now available on RDS

Comment: Oh I had no idea MariaDB is now on RDS. Thank you very much. In other words, upgrading to m3.large is not possible? How does AWS even know that the AMI I create from the snapshot is this MariaDB AMI?

Answer (score 1):

Zed, since I can't comment, I'll let you know here AWS knows that the AMI is a MariaDB AMI because it's specified in the metadata.

Unfortunately, there isn't any way you can bypass this problem save by rebuilding that machine yourself. I'm sure there's a reason  SkySQL Ab doesn't want their customers to use m3.large.